# Select results based on Date but knowing the ID

Tags: mysql

This is table History:

```
URL | UID | Method | Tag | Date
```

And this query:

```
$data = mysql_query("
        select * from History 
        order by `Date` asc         
        ");
```

I need to get the URLs that have an older Date than a record.

I only have the URL of this record. ($url)

Is there is a way to find it and select rows that come before in the order by date?

I can run a separate query with the `$url` to get it's Date but I want to know if it's possible to do it with one query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subselect:

```
SELECT *
FROM History
WHERE Date < (SELECT Date FROM History WHERE url = 'foo')
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Add a unique [index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) to url to ensure that the subquery will only return one record.

Comment: I would also add `LIMIT 1` to nested query

Comment: @Mark what datatype should be for `date` field for the execution of above query??

Comment: @diEcho: No restriction. If the ORDER BY clause works correctly, the WHERE should too. I'd suggest datetime.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better performance then sub-selects:

```
SELECT
  h1.*
FROM
  history h1
INNER JOIN 
  history h2 
ON
  h2.url = '{URL}'
WHERE
  DATEDIFF(h1.`date`,h2.`date`) < 0
```